# Trouble with PHP dropdown inheriting to another page

Tags: php

I am working on a dropdown that was made before i joined the company and it does not inherit to other pages properly. The dropdown defines the ordering of products (alphabetical, descending-asceding etc.) and it works properly on the main pages of the site, but in out newer "new products" and "sale" pages the drop down does not draw properly.

I believe i have to include isset and get features to get the code to properly inherit to other pages, but i am having a difficult time to understand where to include it in the code and what to do with the values.

[On the site it shows up like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDoUe.png)

Here is the code for the dropdown that is supposed to determine order of product listings:

```
$n = sizeof($column_list);
for ($col=0; $col<$n; $col++) {
    $lc_align = '';
    $lc_width = '';

    switch ($column_list[$col]) {
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_MODEL':
            $lc_text = [
                  'asc' => TABLE_HEADING_MODEL,
                  'desc' => 'desccc'
                ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_NAME':
            $lc_text = [
                  'asc' => 'Nimi A-Ö',
                  'desc' => 'Nimi Ö-A'
                ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_MANUFACTURER':
            $lc_text = [
                    'asc' => 'Valmistaja A-Ö',
                    'desc' => 'Valmistaja Ö-A'
                ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_PRICE':
            $lc_text = [
                    'asc' => 'Halvin ensin',
                    'desc' => 'Kallein ensin'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_QUANTITY':
            $lc_text = [
                    'asc' => TABLE_HEADING_QUANTITY,
                    'desc' => 'desccc'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_WEIGHT':
            $lc_text = [
                    'asc' => TABLE_HEADING_WEIGHT,
                    'desc' => 'desccc'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_IMAGE':
            $lc_text = [
                    'asc' => TABLE_HEADING_IMAGE,
                    'desc' => 'desccc'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_LIIKENNEVALOT':
            $lc_text = [
                        'asc' => 'Saatavuus',
                        'desc' => 'desccc'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_BUY_NOW':
            $lc_text = [
                        'asc' => TABLE_HEADING_BUY_NOW,
                        'desc' => 'desccc'
            ];
            break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_ORDERED':
            $lc_text = ['desc' => 'Suosituin ensin'];
            break;
    }

    $lc_text_output = null;

    if (($column_list[$col] != 'PRODUCT_LIST_BUY_NOW') && ($column_list[$col] != 'PRODUCT_LIST_IMAGE') ) 
    {
        $lc_text_output = tep_create_sort_heading($_SESSION['products_sort'], 
                                                $col+1, $lc_text);
        echo $lc_text_output;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: This code does not show us enough for us to be of any real help to you